# NextJS back without history

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Using NextJS router my website is receiving the same image.

```
// user/[id]

  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query as {
    id: string;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{id}</p>
      <img src={...}/>
    </div>
  )
```

On page `user/1` the image is correct. Clicking a button on page to `user/2` displays the correct image for 2. When clicking `back` on the browser or `window.history.back()` to `user/1` the image is still of user 2.

How do I do a complete refresh on the page to ensure the cache isn't used?

Comment: Is the id changing? Please show how you find out the value of `src`

Answer (score 1):

Setting a unique key for the img tag based on the page id will solve it.

```
<img key={id} src={...}/>
```